# Magento 2 API URLs 404 Not Found

Tags: php, api, magento

So, I have a problem with Magento. If I want to access the API i get the "404 Not Found" error.
I have been searching for a solution for quite a while now, but I just can't solve this issue.
I tried following URLs:
http://localhost/m/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl
http://localhost/m/api/soap/?wsdl
and a few others.....

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Yep - Magento sucks. Their documentation is even worse. -840/10 would not recommend.